# calendarWithIdentifier method not available

Tags: ios, xcode, ekeventstore

I am trying to access a calendar using the `EkEventStore` `calendarWithIdentifier`. However Xcode does not show `calendarWithIdentifier` as an option for `EkEventStore`.  I have added the `EventKit` framework, I have the event kit headers in my code, and I have checked the `EkEventStore` header and `calendarWithIdentifier` is in there.  My code does not compile. `calendarWithIdentifier` method doesn't exist.

Some additional details:

- Xcode 6.1.1
- Developing for iPad with iOS 8.1
- OSX 10.9.5

The apple documentation does say that this method is available.

Any help on how to resolve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to show any code? Are you definitely aware of the difference between an instance method and a class method?

Comment: Are you using `EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]; [store calendarWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_YOU_ARE_INTERSTED_IN"];`?

Comment: `- (EKCalendar *)calendarWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` is an instance method (as suggested by @Tommy). Hence you should use it with an instance of type `EKEventStore`. If you use it as `[EKEventStore calendarWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_YOU_ARE_INTERSTED_IN"]` it won't work.